# PHP POST and a function, Im doing something wrong

Tags: php, function, post

Im not sure if POST is not working or if function is not working.
So heres the code for one page:

```
<?php require_once("includes/Functions.php"); ?>
<?php include("includes/front.php"); ?>
<div id="register"> 
<form action="Includes/Functions.php" method="post" name="createUser"> 
Username: <input type="text" name="user" maxlength="16"/><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="pass" maxlength="30"/><br />
Repeat password: <input type="password"/><br />
E-mail: <input type="email" name="mail"/><br />             
<input type="submit" value="Next" />            
</form>
<a href="/login.php">Log in</a>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?>
```

Here is the begining of functions.php:

```
<?php require_once("connect.php"); ?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["createUser"]) && isset($_POST["user"], $_POST["pass"],    $_POST["mail"])){
call_user_func_array("createUser", array($_POST("user"), $_POST("pass"), $_POST("mail")));
}
```

Using echo method of troubleshooting I see that echo is working everywhere in code but not in the function I need.

Here is the function:

```
function createUser ($username, $password, $email){
//Get from form
$username = $_POST["user"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];
$email = $_POST["mail"];
$hashedPassword = sha1($password);
//Submit to database
//make query
$query = ("INSERT INTO users ( username , email , hashPass ) VALUES ( '$username' ,  '$email' , '$hashedPassword')");
//use query
if (mysql_query($query, $connection)) {
//userMade.php
header("Location: ../userMade.php");
exit;
} else {
echo "<p>I suck!</p>";
echo "<p>".mysql_error()."</p>";
} 
}
```

No PHP or MySQL errors are being reported, I only see a blank page.

Comment: please first enable `error reporting`. where is `$connection` ?

Comment: What's the exact point of using `call_user_func_array()` here?

Comment: Please learn about using parametrized queries instead of leaving yourself open to SQL injection like your code does.  http://bobby-tables.com/php.html gives examples.

Comment: Just an FYI. If you have multiple PHP lines in a group like the first two lines of your HTML block above you don't have to open and close the PHP on each line. If you open on the first line and close on the second you'll be just fine.

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', true)` and `error_reporting(E_ALL)` right at the top of your code and try again.

Comment: Error reporting is on, and I fixed all reported errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `functions.php` you are checking `if(isset($_POST["createUser"])...`

The form `name` attribute [is not submitted during the post](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-name-FORM), so this if-statement will always fail.

You will want to use the name/value attribute of the submit button, or a hidden input field in order to satisfy this condition

Comment: name attribute is submitted during the POST because it works in other documents I use.

Answer (score 1):

```
call_user_func_array("createUser", array($_POST("user"), $_POST("pass"), $_POST("mail")));
```

should be

```
call_user_func_array("createUser", array($_POST["user"], $_POST["pass"], $_POST["mail"]));
```

or

```
createUser($_POST["user"], $_POST["pass"], $_POST["mail"]);
```

And you don't have to :

```
$username = $_POST["user"];
$password = $_POST["pass"];
$email = $_POST["mail"];
```

in `createUser` function.

Comment: You can't use $_POST("user") ... $_POST is not a function, it's an array. And I was also helping you cleaning your code.

Comment: @user1642320 I think codea is trying to point out that you are using parentheses when you should be using square brackets, although the comment about clean code is purely subjective.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php require_once("includes/Functions.php"); ?>
<form action="Includes/Functions.php" method="post" name="createUser">
```

Do these 2 lines point to the same file? I would assume so, but the case is not correct. I would start here. I would keep a standard naming convention, as some files are in Caps and some are not.

I would also recommend salting your passwords before hashing.

For your SQL, i recommend using [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo), because your code right now is subject to SQL injection attack, possibly revealing the unsalted passwords.

Comment: I try to keep naming right but this one got away. Thanks for salting reccomendation.